# how to make an animation only 1 time on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nff7wqdm/)

```js
const ratingcount = document.querySelectorAll('.ratingcount');
const totalratingcounter = ratingcount.length;

var stopNow = totalratingcounter

countEach()
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
      countEach()
})

function countEach() {
    $('.ratingcount').each(function() {
        if (showOnScreen(this) && $(this).attr('show') != 'false' && stopNow != 0) {
            console.log($(this).text())
            console.log($(this).attr('show'))
            $(this).attr('show', 'false')
            numberAnimate(this)
            stopNow = stopNow - 1;
        } else if (!showOnScreen(this)) {
            $(this).attr('show', 'true')
        }
    })
}

function showOnScreen(target) {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(target).offset().top)
      return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function numberAnimate(target) {
    var $this = $(target);
    jQuery({
        Counter: 0
    }).animate({
        Counter: $this.text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function() {
            $this.text(this.Counter.toFixed(1));
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
Follow my steps, Scroll down to middle
</h1>
<span class="ratingcount">5.6</span><br/>
<span class="ratingcount">5.6</span>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<span class="ratingcount">5.6</span><br/>
<span class="ratingcount">5.6</span>
<h1>NOW SCROLL UP AGAIN and  then scroll down 
</h1>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<h1>
Now see this is not working 
</h1>
<span class="ratingcount">5.6</span><br/>
<span class="ratingcount">5.6</span>
```

The problem.

```
const ratingcount = document.querySelectorAll('.ratingcount');
const totalratingcounter = ratingcount.length;
```

This code counts the number of `ratingcount` class.

And this code stops the animation after doing animation equal to the number of class

```
var stopNow = totalratingcounter
```

Fair enough right? But, the problem is, a number can do animation multiple times, and other number cannot do it.

Like: If i scroll down to a number in the middle, it will do the animation.

Then, instead of scrolling to the bottom, i scroll up and then again down. 
Then the middle number do animation again, but the bottom number don't because of that.

Comment: do you want each one of them to animate only once?

Comment: yes @ItayGanor, once only + only on scroll (if not shown on screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understood you correctly - You want each rating counter to be animated once, on its first show on screen. To achieve this, all you have to do is removing the `else if() {...}` from your function `countEach()`, As I did below:

```js
const ratingcount = document.querySelectorAll('.ratingcount');
const totalratingcounter = ratingcount.length;

var stopNow = totalratingcounter

countEach()
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
      countEach()
})

function countEach() {
    $('.ratingcount').each(function() {
        if (showOnScreen(this) && $(this).attr('show') != 'false' && stopNow != 0) {
            //console.log($(this).text())
            //console.log($(this).attr('show'))
            $(this).attr('show', 'false')
            numberAnimate(this)
            stopNow = stopNow - 1;
        }/* else if (!showOnScreen(this)) {
            $(this).attr('show', 'true')
        }*/
    })
}

function showOnScreen(target) {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(target).offset().top)
      return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function numberAnimate(target) {
    var $this = $(target);
    jQuery({
        Counter: 0
    }).animate({
        Counter: $this.text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function() {
            $this.text(this.Counter.toFixed(1));
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
Follow my steps, Scroll down to middle
</h1>
<span class="ratingcount">5.6</span><br/>
<span class="ratingcount">5.6</span>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<span class="ratingcount">5.6</span><br/>
<span class="ratingcount">5.6</span>
<h1>NOW SCROLL UP AGAIN and  then scroll down 
</h1>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<h1>
Now see this is not working 
</h1>
<span class="ratingcount">5.6</span><br/>
<span class="ratingcount">5.6</span>
```